# SQL conditional loops with multiple variables

Tags: sql-server, for-loop

I have some calculations and conditions that I want to program actions for, based on one, all or some of the variables, but I cannot figure out the "easy" logic to combine multiple similar scripts into one.

Scenario - I have multiple replication publications in SQL and I calculate the time difference between the source database table and the target database table based off the DATEFIFF between two timestamps. I then had alerts created when it was only 1 (then 2) separate publications. If the difference between the two table times was <= a minute, don't do anything. If it was between 1 and 5 minutes then send me an email with a subject line tailored ("growing latency possible"). If it was between 5 and 15 minutes then send a similar email but a different subject and so on.

I created a SQL job to run every so often and I had one step...then when I had two publications, I created a second step, the same code, but tailored to table 2 instead of table 1. Now I am getting to the point of 5-6 steps and I am wondering if there's a more simplistic way of cycling through things in one steps instead of 5-6 steps. and I end up getting 5 or 6 emails for each run since there's one for each step.

If having the same stuff in 5-6 steps is best then feel free to tell me. Otherwise I am trying to figure out an easy way to do something similar to a FOR EACH loop inside of one condition (<= a minute) but include looking at each of the 5-6 variables. If there are no issues, then send me one email that says "all good" otherwise send me an email for each publication that is running behind.

I have the code set up for the declarations...here's one:

```
    DECLARE @PublicationName1 as varchar (20)  --used in the email message later

    DECLARE 
    @SourceDateTime as DATETIME = 
    (
        SELECT [CanaryDateTime] from [dbo].[ReplicationTestDateTime] WITH (NOLOCK)
    )

    DECLARE
    @TargetDateTime as DATETIME = 
    (
        SELECT [CanaryDateTime] from [SourceSQLServer].[table].[dbo].[ReplicationTestDateTime] WITH (NOLOCK)
    )

    DECLARE @DifferenceMinutes1 as INT =
    (
        Select DATEDIFF(minute, @SourceDateTime, @TargetDateTime)
    )
            
    DECLARE @HLatencyMinutes1 varchar (10)  --this is used in an email message so it's a varchar

    SET @LatencyMinutes1 = @DifferenceMinutes1
```

I have these set up for the 6 different tables, consider them @DifferenceMinutes1, @DifferenceMinutes2, @DifferenceMinutes3, @DifferenceMinutes4, @DifferenceMinutes5 and @DifferenceMinutes6.

The first IF/THEN is pretty easy...if all of the differences are less than or equal to 1, then don't do anything...

```
    IF @DifferenceMinutes1 <= 1  AND @DifferenceMinutes2 <=1 AND @DifferenceMinutes3 <=1 AND @DifferenceMinutes4  <=1 AND @DifferenceMinutes5 <=1 AND @DifferenceMinutes6 <=1 
        BEGIN
            Select 'Excellent';   --essentially this does nothing unless you run this in management studio
        END
```

I used to have an ELSE IF that if the single variable met the condition then send me an email:

```
    ELSE IF (@DifferenceMinutes1 > 1 AND @HDifferenceMinutes1 < 5)
    BEGIN            
    SET @Message =
      '<p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt">There is an error in database replication.  ' + '<br><br>' + 'Replication is beginning to be behind and is between 2 and 5 minutes. ' + '<br><br>' +                 '<b>NOTE:</b> This alert will be generated every 15 minutes until replication is caught up for the databases.  ' + '<br><br>' + 'Current lag time is ' + @LatencyMinutes1 + ' minutes' +                '</p>'

    SET @body_content = @Message

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'DBmail profile name',
    @recipients='emailaddress', 
    @subject='Replication Alert:@PublicationName1 has initial latency', 
    @body=  @body_content,
    @importance='high', 
    @body_format='HTML' 
    Select 'Slight';  -- this last line does nothing really unless you launch in SQL studio
    END
```

What I cannot figure out how to put into commands is this initial logic. I would still need to be sure that if there is an issue in one or more, that it continues and checks all of them.

```
If Diff1 <= 1 then (things are good, go on to Diff2)
If Diff2 <= 1 then (things are good, go on to Diff3)
    If Diff3 <= 1 then (things are good, go on to Diff4)
        If Diff4 <= 1 then (things are good, go on to Diff5)
            If Diff5 <= 1 then (things are good, go on to Diff6)
                If Diff6 <=1 then (everything is good)
                    Send a single "all clear" email
                ELSE IF Diff6 between 1-5 THEN
                    Send 1-5 email for Diff6 stuff
                ELSE IF Diff6 between 5-15 THEN 
                    Send 5-15 email for Diff6 stuff
                ELSE 
                    END 
            ELSE IF Diff5 between 1-5 THEN
                Send 1-5 email for Diff5 stuff
            ELSE IF Diff5 between 5-15 THEN 
                Send 5-15 email for Diff5 stuff
            ELSE 
                END
        ELSE IF Diff4 between 1-5 THEN
            Send 1-5 email for Diff4 stuff
        ELSE IF Diff4 between 5-15 THEN 
            Send 5-15 email for Diff4 stuff
        ELSE
            END
    ELSE IF Diff3 between 1-5 THEN
        Send 1-5 email for Diff3 stuff
    ELSE IF Diff3 between 5-15 THEN 
        Send 5-15 email for Diff3 stuff
    ELSE 
        END
ELSE IF Diff2 between 1-5 THEN
    Send 1-5 email for Diff2 stuff
ELSE IF Diff2 between 5-15 THEN 
    Send 5-15 email for Diff2 stuff
ELSE 
    END
ELSE IF Diff1 between 1-5 THEN
Send 1-5 email for Diff1 stuff
ELSE IF Diff1 between 5-15 THEN 
Send 5-15 email for Diff1 stuff
ELSE
END
```

My initial attempts were to create a condition like <=1 and then do a loop for each of the differences, then go to the next condition >1 and <=5, cycle through a loop and then >5 and <= 15 condition. But I can't figure out the terminology to do this.

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using. The above SQL is product specific. (Perhaps sql-server?)

Comment: Your question is very broad, but i would move all the source/destination table names into some sort of meta data tables, and then by using dynamic sql and cursor/loops, you can fetch the difference. By same logic different thresholds should also be in some meta data tables, so you can generate different emails for different time differences.